# Getting ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED while trying to connect with the backend Docker container from the frontend container

Tags: docker

I am trying to connect with the backend Docker container from the frontend container through this part of the code:

useEffect(() => {
fetch("http://springbootcontainer:8080/laserSafetyGlass/getAllLaserSafetyGlasses")
.then(res => res.json())
.then((result) => {
setLaserSafetyGlasses(result);
})
}, [])

Here, 'springbootcontainer' is the name of the backend Docker container. However, I am getting this error:

GET http://springbootcontainer:8080/laserSafetyGlass/getAllLaserSafetyGlasses net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
(anonymous) @   laserSafetyGlasses-list.js: 64 commitHookEffectListMount @  react-dom.development.js: 23150 commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js: 24926 commitPassiveMountEffects_complete @    react-dom.development.js: 24891
commitPassiveMountEffects_begin @   react-dom.development.js: 24878

I have ensured that the containers are on the same network and have turned off the firewall on my browser. Also, I tried with the IP address in the place of the container name. In this case, I am getting: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.